# Using VirtualBitmapControl from Win2D and load image immediately

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, win2d

New to XAML, UWP, MVVM and Win2D.

I need to display a very large image in my page view. I'm looking at Win2D, specifically at the VirtualBitmapControl and the VirtualBitmapExample.

This is close to what I want to do, but I don't need to pick my image, I already have that information when I navigate to the page.

I tried duplicating the control and removing the file pickers but I can't see where I would be loading my image from the file path to display in the page.

From stepping through with the debugger, the VirtualBitmapControl is initialized before the binding for the file path is even set. To further add another layer, I am also using MVVM so I was trying to encapsulate it all as a UserControl and be able to use it in the same manner as using an Image control.

Here is my XAML code:

```
    <UserControl
    x:Class="PEERNET.UWPImageViewer.Views.VirtualBitmapControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PEERNET.UWPImageViewer.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Win2Dcanvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:VirtualBitmapControl, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
    SizeChanged="Control_SizeChanged"
    Unloaded="Control_Unloaded"
    Loading="Control_Loading"
    Loaded="Control_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for narrow view  -->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for normal view  -->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for wide view  -->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      ZoomMode="Disabled"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      x:Name="ImageScrollViewer">
            <Grid>
                <Win2Dcanvas:CanvasVirtualControl
                    x:Name="ImageVirtualControl"
                    CreateResources="ImageVirtualControl_CreateResources"
                    RegionsInvalidated="ImageVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
    public sealed partial class VirtualBitmapControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VirtualBitmapControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        if (!DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }

        virtualBitmapOptions = CanvasVirtualBitmapOptions.None;
        //virtualBitmapOptions = CanvasVirtualBitmapOptions.CacheOnDemand;
        //virtualBitmapOptions = CanvasVirtualBitmapOptions.ReleaseSource;
    }

    public string LoadedImageInfo { get; private set; }

    public bool IsImageLoaded { get { return virtualBitmap != null; } }


    //StorageFile PhotoAsStorageFile;
    IRandomAccessStream imageStream;

    CanvasVirtualBitmap virtualBitmap;
    CanvasVirtualBitmapOptions virtualBitmapOptions;

    // This is the file we are displaying
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilePathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FilePath.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilePath", typeof(string), typeof(VirtualBitmapControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
                                    //null);

     private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = d as VirtualBitmapControl;
        if (d == null)
            return;

        if (instance.virtualBitmap != null)
        {
            //instance.virtualBitmap.Invalidate();
            //instance.virtualBitmap.InvalidateMeasure();
        }            
    }

    private void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: What do I need to do here?
        ImageScrollViewer.MaxWidth = double.MaxValue;
        ImageScrollViewer.MaxHeight = double.MaxValue;

        /* WIN2d sample code
        if (smallView)
        {
            ImageScrollViewer.MaxWidth = ActualWidth / 4;
            ImageScrollViewer.MaxHeight = ActualHeight / 4;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageScrollViewer.MaxWidth = double.MaxValue;
            ImageScrollViewer.MaxHeight = double.MaxValue;
        }*/
    }

    private void Control_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VirtualBitmapControl::Control_Loading");

    }


    private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VirtualBitmapControl::Control_Loaded");
    }

    private void Control_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VirtualBitmapControl::Control_Unloaded");

        if (ImageVirtualControl != null)
        {
            ImageVirtualControl.RemoveFromVisualTree();
            ImageVirtualControl = null;
        }
    }

    private void ImageVirtualControl_CreateResources(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasVirtualControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VirtualBitmapControl::ImageVirtualControl_CreateResources");
        if (imageStream != null)
        {
            args.TrackAsyncAction(LoadVirtualBitmap().AsAsyncAction());
        }
    }

    private void ImageVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasVirtualControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var region in args.InvalidatedRegions)
        {
            using (var ds = ImageVirtualControl.CreateDrawingSession(region))
            {
                if (virtualBitmap != null)
                    ds.DrawImage(virtualBitmap, region, region);
            }
        }
    }


    private async Task LoadVirtualBitmap()
    {
        if (virtualBitmap != null)
        {
            virtualBitmap.Dispose();
            virtualBitmap = null;
        }

        LoadedImageInfo = "";

        if (imageStream != null)
        {
            imageStream.Dispose();
            imageStream = null;
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged();


        if (imageStream == null)
        {
            imageStream = await GetBitmapStreamFromFilePathAsync(this.FilePath);
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged();


        virtualBitmap = await CanvasVirtualBitmap.LoadAsync(ImageVirtualControl.Device, imageStream, virtualBitmapOptions);

        if (ImageVirtualControl == null)
        {
            // This can happen if the page is unloaded while LoadAsync is running
            return;
        }

        var size = virtualBitmap.Size;
        ImageVirtualControl.Width = size.Width;
        ImageVirtualControl.Height = size.Height;
        ImageVirtualControl.Invalidate();

        LoadedImageInfo = string.Format("{0}x{1} image, is {2}CachedOnDemand",
            size.Width, size.Height, virtualBitmap.IsCachedOnDemand ? "" : "not ");

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        foreach (var property in new string[] { "LoadedImageInfo", "IsImageLoaded", "FilePath"})
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    internal async static Task<IRandomAccessStream> GetBitmapStreamFromFilePathAsync(String filePath)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream imageStream = null;
        <trimmed for space>

        return imageStream;
    }

}
```

And how I am using the control from my page XAML:

```
   <Grid x:Name="rootPhotoGrid" RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Background="AntiqueWhite">
    <local:VirtualBitmapControl FilePath="{x:Bind ViewModel.LoadedImagePath}"/> </Grid>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, or tell me what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing, that would be greatly appreciated.

Sheri

Answer (score 0):

Hook the CreateResources event on your control, and use TrackAsyncAction to let this monitor the progress of a CanvasVirtualBitmap.LoadAsync call.

Check out the code example at http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap.htm

Deeper background info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/win2d/2014/12/05/async-resource-loading-in-win2d/

Comment: This works but CreateResources is only ever called once the very first time I go to that page. I am navigating back and forth to this page from another page (using MVVM and a ViewModel Locater) and I need the new image (selected from the other page and set as the FilePath property on the user control) displayed each time I go into the page. I also had to comment out the unloading of the ImageVirtualControl in Control_Unloaded or I was getting null references when I went back into the page.

Comment: In general I would advise against caching Win2D controls for reuse when a page is revisited. Each Win2D control consumes a significant amount of GPU resources that you really want to release when the page is no longer visible.

You can disable page caching by setting NavigationCacheMode to Disabled (more info at http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-navigation-cache-or-why-going-back-to-previous-page-creates-a-new-instance-of-the-page)

Alternative (more complex) approach: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/win2d/2015/01/29/loading-win2d-resources-from-outside-the-createresources-event/